Reading default registry key value in from a batch script without registry type
I would like to find the proper batch script command line to read the default value of a registry key and store the result in a variable.
I found many examples to achieve this, but all of them keep on storing the registry key type as well.
Here's the script:
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve') DO set "DFMT=%%B"
echo %DFMT%

The result keeps on showing REG_SZ, while I would like to store only the path to excel.exe which is afterwards.
What am I missing?

You're missing debugging. The script tries to parse the output of reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve. So what is the output of that command?

I can't see your problem. It works as you wished. Did you test your minimal example? Please show the full output of reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve it seems that your system shows unexpected things

Your results cannot be replicated. Your command, outside the for loop produces 3 lines. The first is empty, and the second is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\EXCEL.EXE. Both of those lines are being skipped in your FOR /F loop. So that leaves you with one line like this:     (Default)    REG_SZ    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE. With the default delimiters, (as none were added), token 2 (%%A) will be REG_SZ and token * %%B will be the remainder, C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE.

I managed to fix my issue, using:
@echo off
FOR /F "skip=2 tokens=3,*" %%A IN ('reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe" /ve') DO set "DFMT=%%B"
echo %DFMT%


This does not resolve the issue, because, using your own code and output, would propagate %%A with C:\Program, and %%B with Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE.
